Accessing outlook inbox for personal email using imap from Java console application
I am trying to fetch the inbox from my personal email which is @outlook.com. I have created Azure account and created application and as well as secret as well. But I am getting error
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed. I have account type Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox). But I have tried using other options as well.
Below is the code.
 private static String generateAccessToken(String clientId, String clientSecret, String tenantId)
            throws MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
       ConfidentialClientApplication
               app = ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(clientId, ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(clientSecret))
                .authority(authUrl+"/"+tenantId)
                .build();
        ClientCredentialParameters clientCredentialParam = ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(scope)).build();
        CompletableFuture<IAuthenticationResult> future = app.acquireToken(clientCredentialParam);
           boolean isAuthorized = app.validateAuthority();
        System.out.println("isAuthorized = " + isAuthorized);
        System.out.println("url = " + app.authority());
            IAuthenticationResult result = future.get();
            return result.accessToken();

    }

    private static Store getIMAPStore() throws NoSuchProviderException {
        Properties props = getMailIMAPProperties();
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        session.setDebug(true);
        return session.getStore("imaps");
    }

    private static Properties getMailIMAPProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
        props.put("mail.imaps.auth.xoauth2.disable", "false");

        return props;
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        String host = "outlook.office365.com";
        String email = "personal_email@outlook.com";
        String clientId = "client_id";
        String clientSecret = "clientSecret";
        String tenantId = "tenantId";

        String accessToken = generateAccessToken(clientId, clientSecret, tenantId);


        try{
            Store store = getIMAPStore();

            store.connect(host, email, accessToken);

            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            int messageCount = inbox.getMessageCount();
            System.out.printf("Total messages present in the folder 'Inbox' are %d.%n", messageCount);

            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();


            for (Message message : messages) {
                System.out.println(message.getSubject());
            }

            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Below is the some of the setup of azure.



And what is your scope you are passing in in generateAccessToken?

You need to make of user interactive flow to access personal outlook accounts with delegated permissions. You are getting error as you are making use of ConfidentialClientApplication and trying to access  personal outlook accounts

So, I won't be able to create a command line tools by using personal account? I am doing automation work which will later be integrated in CI/CD pipeline. Also, I use some email like @xyz.com, will this work given the admin provides consent?

Yes I guess so @umuieme

@umuieme Is the issue resolved?

@Rukmini I have not used interactive flow as I need it in CI/CD. It is not working for company email as well. I get the accessToken but when I try to connect, it throws A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.. I am currently trying to use http request instead to see if this works or not.

You should try API graph, instead multitenant. Example
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
    .buildClient();

MessageCollectionPage messages = graphClient.me().messages()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();


I am currently trying to make request to the graph API. I am curious Is there any reason that the above method will not work. Is it issue with the code and setup or is the above method is deprecated?
